# PHP Page Title Tag Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: php, mysql, title

I call upon my MySQL database to post the name of a category in the title tag in band_cat_list.php.
This is the code for adding it into the title:

```
BAND_CAT_LIST.PHP
<head>
<?php

    include ('database.php');

    $get_title = "SELECT * FROM `Categories`";

    $run_title = mysql_query($get_title);

    while ($row_title = mysql_fetch_array($run_title)){

        $cat_id   = $row_title['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_title['cat_title'];

        echo "<title>Offstreams - $cat_title</title>";
    }
?>
</head>
```

Inside index.php, I post the categories. The Categories display no problem and when I click on them they go to the appropriate page which is "index.php?band_cat_list&cat=$category_id"

```
INDEX.PHP
 <div class="header_links">
    <ul class="header_ul">
        <?php
            include("includes/database.php"); 

            $get_categories = "select * from Categories";

            $run_categories = mysql_query($get_categories);

            if (!$run_categories) { // add this check.
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($category_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_categories)){

                $category_id = $category_row['cat_id'];
                $category_title = $category_row['cat_title'];

                echo "<li class='header_li' align='center'><a href='index.php?band_cat_list&cat=$category_id'>$category_title</a></li>";
                }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am running PHP 5.4 on my server, so I know the function mysql_fetch_array() isn't deprecated.But I can't figure it out. When I click on any of the categories, it only posts the first one on the list in the title tag. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have multiple title tags in an HTML page.

The code you wrote will output multiple title tags, assuming you have multiple records inside Categories. If I understand what you are trying to do the following should work:

```
<head>
<?php

include ('database.php');

$id = isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : exit("cat id is missing");

$get_title = "SELECT * FROM `Categories` WHERE `cat_id` = '{$id}'";

$run_title = mysql_query($get_title);

while ($row_title = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_title)){

    $cat_id   = $row_title['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row_title['cat_title'];

    echo "<title>Offstreams - $cat_title</title>";
}
?>
</head>
```

PS: you should not use the mysql extension since it is deprecated and no longer maintained. Try using mysqli instead

**UPDATE:**

You should chnage your index.php file to

```
INDEX.PHP
 <div class="header_links">
    <ul class="header_ul">
        <?php
            include("includes/database.php"); 

            $get_categories = "select * from Categories";

            $run_categories = mysql_query($get_categories);

            if (!$run_categories) { // add this check.
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            while ($category_row=mysql_fetch_array($run_categories)){

                $category_id = $category_row['cat_id'];
                $category_title = $category_row['cat_title'];

                echo "<li class='header_li' align='center'><a href='BAND_CAT_LIST.php?band_cat_list&cat=$category_id'>$category_title</a></li>";
                }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The your BAND_CAT_LIST.php should display the title as the "Offstreams - $selected_category"

```
<head>
<?php

include ('database.php');

$id = isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : false;

if($id) {
  $get_title = "SELECT * FROM `Categories` WHERE `cat_id` = '{$id}'";

  $run_title = mysql_query($get_title);

  while ($row_title = mysql_fetch_assoc($run_title)){

      $cat_id   = $row_title['cat_id'];
      $cat_title = $row_title['cat_title'];

      echo "<title>Offstreams - $cat_title</title>";
  }
}
?>
</head>
```

Comment: I have six records to display. The error_log shows no signs of syntax anywhere, so I don't know what the error is. It should display something, but it only displays the first record from the database regardless of the page I'm on.

Comment: @user3638852 what page should display the title tag BAND_CAT_LIST.PHP or INDEX.PHP?

Comment: I'm coding everything on INDEX.PHP and I'm linking the Bands category to BAND_CAT_LIST.PHP where the title tag is along with band listings in the body.

Comment: @MitchMullvain try the updated code and see if that's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Move your `echo` outside your while loop. Also, if `$cat_title` is an array, you will need to convert it to a string and probably format it.

**BAND_CAT_LIST.PHP**

```
<head>
<?php

    include ('database.php');

    $get_title = "SELECT * FROM `Categories`";

    $run_title = mysql_query($get_title);
    $cat_title = array();
    while ($row_title = mysql_fetch_array($run_title)){

        $cat_id   = $row_title['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_title['cat_title'];

    }
    if (is_array($cat_title)) {
        $cat_title = implode(" - ", $cat_title);
    }
    echo "<title>Offstreams - $cat_title['cat_title']</title>";
?>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried that, but instead of displaying the first record from database which is "Home", it is now displaying only the last one which is "Other". I put it in the while loop hoping that it would refresh based on category being accessed.

Comment: Ok, that is because you have not specified that `$cat_title` needs to be an array and hold multiple values. It is only holding one value. I will update my answer.

Comment: It still seems to not be working properly. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: One of your best friends in programming is debugging, and that's what you need to do here. Output your variables every step of the way until you find out why you are not getting the results you expect.

Comment: You don't need to insert any "debugging", you just need to echo/print_r your variables during each process to find out what they contain. The only challenge I see with what you're doing is determining whether your are returning one record or multiple.

Comment: The kicker is when I tried that, it displayed all of the categories along with their id's in the body, but the title tag itself remained unchanged. But there has to be a way to change the title tag based on what is appearing on the page without making six million pages.